# Why is this byte to struct de-serialization unit test failing?

Tags: c#, arrays, unit-testing, struct

I have this simple struct:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct TestStruct
{
    public bool Valid;     // 1
    public UInt64 Value1;  // 8 
    public UInt64 Value2;  // 8
    public float Value3;   // 4
}
```

and this generic from byte array to struct method:

```cs
public static T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
{
    var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try 
    {
        return (T) Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    }
    finally 
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

and this simple unit test:

```cs
[Test]
public void BytesToMyStruct()
{
    const bool Valid = true;
    const UInt64 Value1 = 1;
    const UInt64 Value2 = 2;
    const UInt64 Value3 = 99;

    var validBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Valid);
    var value1Bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Value1);
    var value2Bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Value2);
    var value3Bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Value3);  

    // 1 + 8 + 8 + 4 = 21
    var testBytes = new byte[21];

    Array.Copy(validBytes, 0, testBytes, 0, 1);
    Array.Copy(value1Bytes, 0, testBytes, 1, 8);
    Array.Copy(value2Bytes, 0, testBytes, 9, 8);
    Array.Copy(value3Bytes, 0, testBytes, 17, 4);

    var myStruct = ByteUtils.ByteArrayToStructure<TestStruct>(testBytes);

    Assert.That(myStruct.Valid, Is.EqualTo(true));
    Assert.That(myStruct.Value1, Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(myStruct.Value2, Is.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(myStruct.Value3, Is.EqualTo(99));
}
```

In this unit test I simply wish to manually populate a byte array, deserialize to a struct, and ensure the properties of the struct equal those which were set in the byte array. I assume my approach of manually copying to the same byte array via `Array.Copy` repeatedly is failing due to the fact that when I execute my unit test, I receive a failure stating that `Value1` is not being set correctly:

```
Expected: 1
But was:  0
```

I am not sure if I am setting my byte arrays correctly by manually setting them for unit testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default marshaling behavior for `System.Boolean` is as a 4 byte integer in accordance with the Microsoft/Windows API definition of `BOOL`. So `Marshal.PtrToStructure` assumes that the unmanaged representation of `TestStruct` is 24 bytes large with the first 4 bytes being taken up by `TestStruct.Valid`, which throws off `Value1` and the other fields.

You can change this behavior by applying the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]` attribute to the `bool` field.

Comment: That explains the 3 unaccounted for bytes, thank you!